# Inconsistency when i look on a 'depth' of a set

Tags: set-theory

I tried to define the n-th depth of a set:
$D_n(S)=\{D_{n-1}(s)|s\in S\}$ where $D_0(S)=\emptyset$

for example:

- $D_2(\{\ \{\}\ ,\ \{\{\{\}\}\}\ \})=\{\ \{\}\ ,\ \{\{\}\}\ \}$
- $D_2(\{\ \{\}\ ,\ \{\{\}\}\ ,\ \{\{\{\}\}\}\ \})=\{\ \{\}\ ,\ \{\{\}\}\ \}$

Then I defined $D(S)=(D_n(S))_{n=0}^\infty$ with the idea that every set can be defined with its series. but then i noticed that there are only $\aleph_0$ distinct series-es because $|Im(D_n)|\in\mathbb{N}$.

**an example for a contradiction:**

let define $A_0=\emptyset,A_{n+1}=\{A_n\}$ and let notice that $D_n(A_m)=A_{max\{n,m\}}$ (can be proven recursively [more information in edit2])

now let define $A=\{A_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ so $|A|=\aleph_0$ and $|P(A)|>\aleph_0$.
so there are $S,T\subseteq A$ two distinct subsets such that $D(S)=D(T)$ (because there are only $\aleph_0$ distinct serieses as i said before)

but then because $S\neq T$ there is $A_n$ such that $S\ni A_n\notin T$ (we can swap T,S if needed)

now $D_{n+1}(A_n)\in\{D_{n+1}(s)|s\in S\}=D_{n+2}(S)=D_{n+2}(T)=\{D_{n+1}(t)|t\in T\}$
so there is $A_m\in T$ such that $D_{n+1}(A_m)=D_{n+1}(A_n)$ so $A_{min\{n+1,m\}}=A_n$ so $min\{n+1,m\}=n$ then $m=n$ so $A_n=A_m\in T$. **contradiction!**

**so:** where is my mistake? Do I have any?

##### edit:

In short I found an injective function from $P(A)$ to $B$ where $|A|=\aleph_0$ and $|B|=\aleph_0$ so $2^{\aleph_0}\le\aleph_0$

##### edit2:

we can prove that $D_n(A_m)=A_{min\{n,m\}}$ like the following:

if $n \ge m$ then
$D_n(A_m)=\{D_{n-1}(s)|s\in A_m\}=\{D_{n-1}(A_{m-1})\}=\{\{D_{n-2}(A_{m-2})\}\}=...=\{\{\{...\{D_0(A_{m-n})\}...\}\}\}=\{\{\{...\{\emptyset\}...\}\}\}=A_m$

if $n \le m$ then $D_n(A_m)=\{D_{n-1}(s)|s\in A_m\}=\{D_{n-1}(A_{m-1})\}=\{\{D_{n-2}(A_{m-2})\}\}=...=\{\{\{...\{D_{n-m}(A_0)\}...\}\}\}=\{\{\{...\{\emptyset\}...\}\}\}=A_n$

Comment: Im(D_n) is what?

Comment: It works great to understand how $\omega$ corresponds to a tree, and in what sense that tree has no infinite branches.

Comment: @SamGinrich Im(D_n) is the set all the sets with depth of at most n

Comment: @AsafKaragila i don't understand, what is $\omega$?

Comment: Let $0=\varnothing$ and $n+1=n\cup\{n\}$. Then $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers. It's the smallest infinite set, and indeed it *is* $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So how does it fix the issue. i found an injective function from P(A) to some group with cardinal $\aleph_0$ so $\aleph<=\aleph_0$

Comment: I didn't say it fixes the issue. I said it could help and clarify it.

Comment: @Asaf ω the cardinal number of IN ?

Comment: @SamGinrich: In the context of set theory, it *is* $\Bbb N$, and since it is also an initial ordinal, it is a cardinal. So, yes.

Comment: @Ofek As you assume D not injective, seems like ´D injective´ proven. Can this be?

Comment: @SamGinrich that's exactly the contradiction, i proved that D is injective, but it can't be because then $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_0$

Comment: @SamGinrich  the fact that D is a function from a set $P(A)$ with cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$ to a set with cardinal $\aleph_0$ means its not injective. and then I disproved it.

Comment: Yes, I'm stuck at " |P(A)|>ℵ0. so there are  ..." why is this? We have in common case infinite T and S and it's NOT obvious to me what happens with the "Amax{n,m}". Cannot follow this without breaking it down elementary.

Comment: @SamGinrich i edited to clarify, this is because i said before "there are only $\aleph_0$ distinct series-es"

Comment: @SamGinrich also added more information about $A_{min\{n,m\}}$

Comment: "but then i noticed that there are only $\aleph_0$ distinct series-es because $|Im(D_n)|\in\mathbb{N}$." Why is that true? There are more than $\aleph_0$ distinct infinite binary sequences even though there are only finitely many possible values for each term.

Comment: Remains basic question: Why this construction with nested sets, is this different from writing down the depth as natural number?

Comment: @SamGinrich you could look on it as a cut of the set from a certain depth.

Answer (score 0):

So the mistake was at

> i noticed that there are only $\aleph_0$ distinct series-es

my thought was: we can count the elements by iterating every element in series.
something like:

00000...,10000...,01000...,11000...,02000...,12000...,00100...,...

but then i miss the series 01010101010101...

(the numbers are corresponding to elements of $Im(D_n)$)

but the cardinal of $Im(D)$ is still limited (probably to $\aleph$) and its weird because its means that we can't distinct between two sets by looking on the depth. but if you look on $P(P(A))$, this set doesn't even have an infinite nesting (like every nesting is finite, not something like $S\in S$)

Comment: Now, has this impact to the infinity of A?